# Is there any software similar to 3dsom,123d?

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine, 3dsmax, 3d-modelling, 3ds

I can't found some opensource project witch is used to convert 2d photograph to 3d models.
3Dsom or 123d provided by autodesk  can work but I can't pay for them.
Someone is using any software like them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try [Make3D](http://make3d.cs.cornell.edu/). I haven't used it personally so I can't vouch for it.